# How to avoid adding a new row to the first row of subtotaled ranges to protect Subtotal formula

Tags: vba, excel, subtotal

I have a Excel sheet, which includes many groups and subgroups. Each subgroup has their own subtotal. And as long as I can't know how many lines users will require for the subgroups, I only left 3 rows blank for each subgroup and created a button which triggers Automatically Copy and Insert Copied Row macro.

Now I need to avoid users to trigger the button while they are on the First and the Last row of any subgroup. (If you copy and insert first row, subtotal formula doesn't recognise the new added line because it will be out of the range and Last row has another specific formulas which I don't want users to copy above)

I've been searching SO and the other Excel blogs for a long time but because of my list is very dynamic and have many different subtotals none of them was suitable to my case.

How can I define all of the first and last rows of my different subtotal ranges (and maybe their Title's rows) to avoid them being copied and then inserted above?

[image: Please also refer to the printscreen of my excel sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine 2 ways to do this. When the "New Row" button is pressed check if the current row is a headline/subheadline whatever …

1. by checking its format (eg specific background color etc).

   ```
   If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Interior.Color = 15004911 Then 
       'copy that row
   End If
   ```
2. or by using an extra helper column that specifies the rows as header rows or non copyable rows. If you don't want the helper column to be seen you can hide it.

   ```
   If Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("X" & iRow).Value = "Header" Then 
       'copy that row
   End If
   'where X is the helper column
   ```

   And if it is a headline row then deny the copy process.

Comment: The second option seems like possible option but I have many columns and macros. Some of them are only working if all the columns are unhidden, So that  (I am not %100 sure but) I might have unhidden hided columns somewhere in the sheet by one of the macros. So I don't want it to be unhidden anytime to the users. It's a bit risky for the professionalism of the tool I think. For the first option it will again be the same because I already have different colors to show it fancy.

Comment: @Mertinc OK, but we agree that you need to detect which type of row the current row is to solve that issue. I definitely see no other way than to distinguish between A) rows that are allowed to be duplicated and B) rows that are *not* allowed to be duplicated. To determine which type of row you have you need to identify it by any marker (format, helper column, content, ...). So your exercise is to find a suitable marker for that task. You can't say I want to fly to the moon, but I don't like to use a rocket when only rockets can fly to the moon. You will have to opt for the lesser evil.

Comment: Hi Peh, after a very long time today I had to do something on this issue and changing background colour of the cells that I don't want them to be copied what I did.(But I choose the column out of print layout, so this different colour doesn't shown anywhere.) Could you please increase your answer on that suggestion so that I can select this as an answer. (For instance how can we avoid some specific rows to be copied? in this case, based on their background colour.) So can you include in your answer, how to write `if Range("A" & row ).interior.color=15004911 Then avoid copying this entire row`

Comment: @Mertinc I added some code examples if that is what you meant.

Comment: Exactly that's good, but any suggestions for `avoid copying this entire row`?

Comment: @Mertinc Inverse `If` with `If Not` is the solution to this, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way that doesn't involve programming have your sum range extend into rows that won't change. So you could start the subtotal in the header row (assuming there is no content in the relevant cell in that row). Another way is to have a hidden row at the top and bottom of each sum range and that is included in the sum range. So you would sum rows 10 to 14, but 10 and 14 would be hidden (and empty) and the user would just get shown rows 11, 12 and 13. Adding a new row would push the hidden rows down and extend the subtotal.

Another way is to use the indirect function.

Say your formula was

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,H7:H10)
```

If you use indirect for the lower bound, it will always refer to the cell immediately above, regardless of how many rows are added in between.

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,H7:INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-1))
```

And taking it one step further, use the upper title row as the anchor to always add up the gap between the title and the subtotal.

```
 =SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT("H"&ROW(H6)+1):INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-1))
```

Comment: header row already has their own subtotal formula so first option is not possible. And for the second one I don't want to have any hiden rows because row numbers are important for the users. I don't want them to be confused.

Comment: How about using indirect?

Comment: that formula is very smart for subtotal formula. (Except I can't easily see the range by clicking F2, because of using indirect within subtotal formula) But still I can apply this (as it's locked for users to view and edit the formulas) But what about avoiding the title and below row to be copied and inserted?

Comment: When you click on the formula, it will highlight the cell directly above the range, so you can see that it will add all the cells above the formula right up to, but not including, the highlighted cell. With regards to adding rows, if you added some background colour to the  Minor items 0.0% rows (which is where I assumed your formula was) then you can just check for a cell background colour, and then only copy the row if the cell has no background.

Comment: A decade or more ago I created  a workbook that had some parts that were protected etc and sent out to other users. From memory, a macro evicted the user from any cells they weren't allowed in (I think it moved the active cell to one they were allowed in) and in order to ensure that the macro ran, the worksheets were all automatically hidden until opened by the macro, so opening the workbook with macros disabled didn't gain them access.

Comment: Hi @Kev, after a very long time, today I had to use your suggestion, which is changing the background colours of the cells that I want to avoid them to be copied, (but I did it somewhere out of my print layout) But as Peh was earlier than you, I am going to choose his response as an answer.